# Streaming XML from NetServer in Vert.X

Tags: java, xml, tcp, vert.x

I'm trying to get make a Verticle than runs a TcpServer which then reads XML asynchronously from incomming connections, stores all xml it receives into a PriorityQueue and then broadcasts XML messages from the Queue.

I'm using a NetServer that reads incoming data from accepted NetSocket connections, but I don't know how to parse the stream data by xml. If I use the standard handler, which converts Buffer to String, I'm getting cut off messages.
I've managed to get it mostly working by creating a RecordParser that deliminates by the XML's end tag, but that's more of a band-aid. If I were to get a lot of bad data before the Xml message, that would be included.

When I use straight netty, it has an option for an XMLFrameDecoder which worked, but is there some way to achieve this in Vert.x?

Here's what I have so far

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
    NetServerOptions options = new NetServerOptions()
            .setPort(mPort)
            .setTcpKeepAlive(true);
    mServer = vertx.createNetServer(options);
    mServer.connectHandler(new Handler<NetSocket>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(NetSocket netSocket) {
            netSocket.handler(RecordParser.newDelimited("</root>", new Handler<Buffer>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
                    String xml = buffer.getString(0, buffer.length()) + "</root>";
                    XMLMessage message = new XMLMessage (xml);
                    System.out.println(xml);
                }
            }));
        }
    });
    mServer.listen();
}
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RecordParser` in Vert.x which would do the same job as Netty's `XMLFrameDecoder`.

It is possible though to [integrate custom Netty servers](https://github.com/vietj/vertx-materials/blob/master/src/main/asciidoc/output/Integrating_Netty.adoc) with the Vert.x programming model.